# How to show full screen notification when receives Firebase push notification and app is closed and phone is "sleeping"/with screen off?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I need to show some important notifications that are time sensitive and need to wake up the android phone and show full screen intent notification even if phone is "sleeping" when receive an Firebase notification. How can i do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message if this is what you asked for

Comment: have you achieved that?